# Xamarin forms- Fill and expand the entry or editor in Xamarin forms all platforms

Tags: android, ios

I need a fill and expand function to my editor field, in layout options have fill and expand, that works for iOS only but not for android and windows phone, I want it to expand without pressing the enter key. It should expand whenever the paragraph has more lines typed.

xaml code:

```
<ContentView Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
    <Editor x:Name="Ed_Notes" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="Black"
            FontSize="{x:Static views:FontSizeView.CustomFontSizeMeMeMe}" TextChanged="Ed_TextChanged"></Editor>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: My Editor adds another line when the line has more characters than fit to the width. The problem is making the Editor expand vertically. According to xamarin devs it's not possible. Well, they say it's possible with a custom renderer so it makes no sense for them to say it's impossible to make it the default behavior, but... That's the xamarin dev team logic.